# Unhandled Rejection in react/firebase chat

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I build a chat app using firebase and React.
When I send a message to a user, that i already have a chat with, it works out well.
I did't write a function for creating a new chat yet, so far I'd just like to see a console log message "new chat".

But when firebase can't find a chat that already exists in database, it throws an error. I can't figure out why.
[Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
DashboardComponent.addMsg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0SL3.png)

Here's the structure of my base - collections chats  - documents
nata@gmail.com:pata@gmail.com (my docKey)- messages and users

[structure of my base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni3UP.png)

Piece of New chat component which is nested into Dashboard:

```
class NewChatComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      friendsEmail: null,
      mess: null
    } 
  }
    
    submitForm = (e) => {
      //     pata@gmail.com
      const chat = this.docKey();
      this.chatExists() ? this.goToExistChat() : this.createChat();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    createChat = () => {
      console.log('new chat')
    }

    goToExistChat = () => {
      const docKey = this.docKey();
      const mess = this.state.mess;
      this.props.goToExistChat(docKey, mess);
    }
    
    docKey = () => {
      const friend = this.state.friendsEmail;
      const docID = [this.props.email, friend].sort().join(':');
      console.log(`doc id : ` + docID)
      return docID;
    }

    chatExists = async () => {
      const docKey = this.docKey();
      const chat = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('chats')
        .doc(docKey)
        .get();
        
      return chat.exists;
    }
```

The parent Dashboard component

```
class DashboardComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          chats: [],
          email: null,
          selectedChat: null,
          chatVisible: false,
          newMessages: true,
          newChatFormVisible: false
        }    
      }
      
      render () {
        return (
            <div className='dashboard-cont'>
              <div className='dashboard'>
                <button className='newChatButton'
                  onClick={this.showNewChatForm}>
                  New Chat
                  </button>   
                  
                { this.state.newChatFormVisible ? <NewChatComponent email={this.state.email}
                goToExistChat={this.goToExistingChat}>
                  </NewChatComponent> :  null
                }                 
              </div>
            </div>
        )}
    
    
      goToExistingChat = async (docKey, msg) => {  
        const friend = docKey.split(':')[1];
        const chat = this.state.chats.find(chat => chat.users.includes(friend));
        const index = this.state.chats.indexOf(chat);
        await this.chooseChat(index);
        this.addMsg(msg);
      }
    
      buildDocId = (friend) => [this.state.email, friend].sort().join(':');
    
      //send msg to the chat & add msg to chat.messages array - THROWS AN ERROR IF FRIEND DOESN'T EXIST
      
     addMsg = (msg) => {
        const friend = this.state.chats[this.state.selectedChat].**users**.filter(user => user !== 
        this.state.email)[0];
        console.log(friend)
        const docId = this.buildDocId(friend);
        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection('chats')
          .doc(docId)
          .update({
            messages: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
              message: msg,
              sender: this.state.email,
              timestamp: Date.now()
            })
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I should have stored a value returned from a promise in a variable.

```
submitForm = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const chat = this.docKey();
      const chatExists = await this.chatExists();
      chatExists ? console.log('pass to the exist chat') : console.log('create new one');
    }
```

instead of
this.chatExists() ? this.goToExistChat() : this.createChat();